# Cannot open embedded mov file in Safari

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, html5-video

I want to play an embedded .mov video in Safari on an iPad.

```hmtml
<video id="sampleMovie" width="640" height="360" preload controls>
    <source src="1.mov" type="video/mov">
</video>
```

If I test that code in Chrome using my desktop, it will works perfectly.
Using iPad and iPhone, it won't play it at all.

Comment: Can you share link to an example video that will not play and also the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Please change file extension from .mov to .mp4 and you can add its embedded movie file. Therefore, you can play the movie file.